# Create a list in Python from response from openai

Tags: python

I am query openai and asking for a list. Openai is bringing back a string as below

"\n\n1. Goalkeeper\n2. Defender\n3. Midfielder\n4. Forward\n5. Left winger\n6. Right winger\n7. Left back\n8. Right back\n9. Center back\n10. Goal scorer"

I want to split this string into a list which only lists the text.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Thanks, that nearly worked apart from the last string still has a full stop
[' Goalkeeper', ' Defender', ' Midfielder', ' Forward', ' Left winger', ' Right winger', ' Left back', ' Right back', ' Center back', '. Striker']

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
string = "\n\n1. Goalkeeper\n2. Defender\n3. Midfielder\n4. Forward\n5. Left winger\n6. Right winger\n7. Left back\n8. Right back\n9. Center back\n10. Goal scorer"
string1 = string
while True:
    string2 = re.sub("\d.", ".", string1)
    if string1 == string2:
        string = string1
        break
    else:
        string1=string2
string=string.split("\n.")
x=0
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[x]=="\n":
        string.remove(string[x])
    else:
        x+=1
print(string)
for i in range(len(string)):
    string[i]=re.sub(".", "", string[i])
```

Here u go sorry its a bit messy and I am sure there would be an easier way to do this but here is one way.

Comment: This is a fine answer, but don't forget to answer the question that might not be being asked; how do I get to this answer in similar situations/problems in the future? Otherwise, we're just writing code for someone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, that nearly worked apart from the last string still has a full stop [' Goalkeeper', ' Defender', ' Midfielder', ' Forward', ' Left winger', ' Right winger', ' Left back', ' Right back', ' Center back', '. Striker']

Comment: Fixed now just added at the end to iterate through the list and remove any dots